# Plugin : Publisher over ftp Why Global Variable defined in pipeline environment do not known by ftpPublisher

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, publish

all !

I have a problem with Plugin Publisher over ftp in pipeline code. I set APP_NAME  in     "environment {APP_NAME='123'}" on top of pipeline code.   but the variable "APP_NAME"  not to be  konwn by ftpPublisher。

and  same as BUILD_NUMBER  JOB_NAME etc  vars  to be known by ftpPublisher.

Any people can help me ? thank you very very much !!!

and my jenkins ver is 2.164.2   ,Publish over ftp ver is 1.15 .

```
pipeline {

    environment {
       APP_NAME='123'
    }

   ......

   stages {

        stage('1. git pull') {

            steps {

                git(

                    branch: 'release',

                    credentialsId: '*****',

                    url : '*********',

                    changelog: true

                )

                sh "ls -lat"

            }

        }

        stage('2. build') {

            steps {

                sh 'cnpm install'

                sh 'bower install --allow-root'

                sh 'gulp goluk:pro'

                sh 'mkdir -p $APP_NAME target'

                sh 'cp -rf dist/* $APP_NAME/'

                sh 'tar jcvf $APP_NAME.tar.bz2 $APP_NAME/'

                sh 'ls -lh'

                sh 'mv $APP_NAME.tar.bz2 target/$APP_NAME.tar.bz2'

                sh 'rm -rf $APP_NAME'

            }

        }

        stage('3. send to ftp') {

            steps {

                sh 'printenv'

                ftpPublisher( 
                  masterNodeName: 'master' , 
                  paramPublish: [parameterName: ''],
                  alwaysPublishFromMaster: false, 
                  continueOnError: false, 
                  failOnError: false, 
                  publishers: [
                    [ configName: 'ftpServer_250', 
                      transfers: [
                        [ asciiMode: false, 
                          cleanRemote: false, 
                          excludes: '', 
                          flatten: false, 
                          makeEmptyDirs: true, 
                          noDefaultExcludes: false, 
                          patternSeparator: '[, ]+', 
                          remoteDirectory: '${APP_NAME}/$BUILD_NUMBER($BUILD_ID)', 
                          remoteDirectorySDF: false, 
                          removePrefix: '', 
                          sourceFiles: 'target/*.tar.bz2'
                        ]
                      ], 
                      usePromotionTimestamp: false, 
                      useWorkspaceInPromotion: false, 
                      verbose: true
                    ]
                   ]
                 )
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change to `remoteDirectory: "${APP_NAME}/$BUILD_NUMBER($BUILD_ID)"`